# Андроид проблемы с fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Здравствуйте.Имеются два фрагмента **А** и **Б**.На фрагменте **А** есть кнопка по нажатию на которую открывается фрагмент **Б** и запоминается в стеке **addToBackStack**.Фрагмент **Б** в потоке делает свои дела и после отработки фрагмент **Б** должен скрыться **popBackStack**.Все работает как надо до тех пор пока я не нажал **кнопку домой**.Нажал **кнопку домой** приложение скрылось, но поток еще работает,закончив работу он вызывает **getFragmentManager().popBackStack()** и тут мы фрагмент **Б** не скрывается а остается.Далее если в процессе работы потока **заблокировать экран** то приложение падает с ошибкой

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
```

Как сделать так что бы **getFragmentManager().popBackStack()** работал и при свернутом приложении и при заблокированном экране?

Answer (score 0):

У вас архитектурная проблема. У вас "слеплены" длительная операция в фрагменте и сам фрагмент.

Если эта операция неотделима от фрагмента, при наступлении onPause()/onStop() операция тоже должна остановиться.

Либо необходимо отделить выполнение этой операции от фрагмента, сохранять полученный в фоне результат, и при повторном появлении приложения на экране показывать тот или иной фрагмент в зависимости от этого результата.

Comment: Так нет способа поставить AsyncTask на паузу.

Comment: Я знаю. Для таких случаев второй вариант.

Comment: Я тогда третий свой использую через скрытие показ лэйаутов